# I can't load PDF.js lib in Lightning Web Component

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, libraries

I'm creating an lwc component that shows a pdf with canvas, the lib I'm using is this:[PDF,js](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/) 
when trying to load lib, returns me an undefined error, can someone help me how to load correctly

[image]
[image]

My Html

```
<template>
<lightning-card>
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="the-canvas" class="canvas" lwc:dom="manual"></canvas>
    </div>
</lightning-card>    
</template>
```

My Js

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
import PdfViewerJs from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfViewer';

export default class compC21Body extends LightningElement {

 renderedCallback() {
    const jsPath = PdfViewerJs + '/pdf.js';
    window.console.log(jsPath);

    loadScript(this, jsPath).then(() => {
        window.console.log('success');
    }).catch(error => {
        window.console.log(error);
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Error Pdf Viewer',
                message: error ? error.message : 'We get error to load some script :/',
                variant: 'error',
            }),
        );
    });
  }
}
```

I put the lib build folder inside the statistic feature in salesforce
Inside the static resource folder we have the files

- pdf.js
- pdf.js.map
- pdf.worker.js
- pdf.worker.js.map

if you have any library suggestions, I just need it to use canvas and not iframe

error update
[image]
SecureElement does not allow access to charset

[image]
Failed to load script at /resource/1573759295000/pdfViewer/pdf.js: regeneratorRuntime is not defined [regeneratorRuntime is not defined]

Comment: Can you access your static resource if you hit the URL directly in your browser?

Comment: yes I tested, and it works :(

Comment: Besides seeing the error in the console of the browser (it looks like you are using Chrome), can you see if the actual resource is being loaded in the `Network` tab and see if it has the correct path? Also see if it is throwing a `200`, `404` or `500`

Comment: guys saw here that the error is: "SecureElement does not allow access to charset", know if you can disable lock service on  lightning web component

Comment: This essentially means that the resource you are trying to load is not "Locker Compliant". You may want to load your resource in the Locker Console https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console and see where exactly it is throwing the issue

Comment: I don't know if I used the tool correctly, but it gave some things I can't use

Comment: So, you should have been able to just paste all the contents of pdf.js in there, and the locker tool would have highlighted what the issues were.

Comment: So putting the source code of `pdf.js` in there threw a Locker violation of `Error: possible html comment syntax rejected around line 17693` That's most likely why it is not loading correctly.

Comment: I tried to do as you told me and returned the following error: Error: possible html comment syntax rejected around line 17548

in line have this :

            case '!':
              if (s.substring(j + 1, j + 3) === '--') {
                q = s.indexOf('-->', j + 3);

                if (q < 0) {
                  this.onError(XMLParserErrorCode.UnterminatedComment);
                  return;
                }

Comment: @BryanAnderson could you post the line of code that threw the error? I see something different in the code about a URL property being touched when it shouldn't be. The locker console seems to be giving strange errors that do not seem consistent.

Comment: @AlefRibeiro Any luck with pdf.js? It had stopped working in Spring 2020

Comment: @OlesMalkov is working normally here, we had to make some adaptations in the library to work properly

Comment: @AlefRibeiro would you mind posting them here as an answer to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uploading just the pdf js file in a separate static resource and pdf worker js in a separate static resource and load pdf js first and worker js next.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import PDFJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfJS';
import PDFWORKER from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdfWorker'
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';
export default class PdfPoc extends LightningElement {
    scale = 1;
    connectedCallback(){
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, PDFJS), loadScript(this, PDFWORKER )]).then(()=>{
            console.log('PDF JS loaded');
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = PDFWORKER;
            this.paintCanvas();
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(' Error loading scripts '+ error);
        })
    }
```

Comment: Can you please share `this.paintCanvas();` code as well ?

Comment: @Manjunatha V P could you please share `this.paintCanvas();` code. I want to render pdf as image. You can answer a similar question here [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/375749/lwc-render-pdf-files-as-images-using-pdfjs)

Comment: @manjunathavp - I got my PDFJS to work inside a lightning-container, which limits the application inside an iframe - did your PDFJS work outside of this limitation?

Comment: This didn't work for me, I get the following error from console:
WARNING: Failed to load script at /resource/1685230586000/PDFjsLibrary: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'pdfjsLib') [Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'pdfjsLib')]

Comment: When I try to print the error received from the .catch() I get undefined