# LWC: Render PDF files as images using pdfjs

Tags: lightning-web-components, pdf, js, third-party

***TLDR: Any working implementation of pdf.js or other 3rd party js to render pdf as images in LWC would be helpful.***

[image]

I want to render pdf pages as images in order to plot dynamic SVGs. Similar to image shown above with svg on 'D' .Most articles suggest using PDF.js for this. I was able to load pdfjs static resources as mentioned [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/285052/i-cant-load-pdf-js-lib-in-lightning-web-component/313878#313878). But when I try to use getDocument, I get **[Cannot read property 'document' of undefined]** which I fixed using `globalThis = window;`. But it is further stuck with `structuredClone()`, it's restricted by Locker services.
Any help around this would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'd like to know if there are any other 3rd party libraries that can be used for this.

Below is the sample code

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import PDFJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdf_js';
import PDFWORKER from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/pdf_worker'
import { loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class PdfjsTest extends LightningElement {
    scale = 1;
    connectedCallback(){
        Promise.all([loadScript(this, PDFJS), loadScript(this, PDFWORKER )]).then(()=>{
            globalThis = window;
            pdfjsLib.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = PDFWORKER;
            console.log('PDF JS loaded' + JSON.stringify(pdfjsLib));
            var url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mozilla/pdf.js/ba2edeae/examples/learning/helloworld.pdf'
            pdfjsLib.getDocument(url)
            .then(result => {
                console.log(result._pdfInfo.numPages)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
        }).catch((error)=>{
            console.log(' Error loading scripts '+ error);
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: An easier approach would be to develop a vf page to create pdf doc and embed it in a lightning component.

Comment: @devforce The pdf doc already exists. I want to plot clickable svgs on the images from the pdf. Please refer attached image.

Comment: Have you considered checking out [Lightning Web Security](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_lwsec_intro)?

Comment: Thanks @FelixvanHove,
When I enable LWS it gives **DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': #<Object> could not be cloned.** Seems to be the right way, but doesn't fix this issue. If I set `globalThis = window` it gives **TypeError: structuredClone is not a function**

Comment: StructuredClone isn't a supported part of the SecureWindow. So when the lwc framework changes Window to SecureWindow, you lose that function. You can try adding a polyfill for structuredclone. It looks like a few are available